# Properties of slice of structs as function argument without allocating slice

Tags: go

I have a slice of structs that looks like:

```
type KeyValue struct {
  Key   uint32
  Value uint32
}

var mySlice []Keyvalue
```

This slice `mySlice` can have a variable length.

I would like to pass all elements of this slice into a function with this signature:

```
takeKeyValues(keyValue []uint32)
```

Now I could easily allocate a slice of `[]uint32`, populate it with all the keys/values of the elements in `mySlice` and then pass that slice as an argument into `takeKeyValues()`...

But I'm trying to find a way of doing that without any heap allocations, by directly passing all the keys/values on the stack. Is there some syntax trick which allows me to do that?

Comment: Are you exclusively using 32bit systems? Most things are 64bit, and will have a different memory layout.

Comment: @JimB, no the code is running on 32 and 64 bit systems

Comment: ah nevermind, you changed the types in the question to have specific sizes.

Comment: ah yes, sorry about that

Comment: Here's another way of looking at this which may or may not be useful for you. Can you write `takeKeyValues` to take an interface instead of `[]uint32`? That interface could have a method to get a value given an index and also a method to give a length if you need that. Then, you could define `[]KeyValue` as a type and define those methods on that type.

Comment: @AndySchweig thx, that's a good idea, i haven't thought of that. I'm not sure if I'll end up doing that because `takeKeyValues()` is a library function which is not that easy to modify, but I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no safe way to arbitrarily reinterpret the memory layout of the your data. It's up to you whether the performance gain is worth the use of an unsafe type conversion.

Since the fields of `KeyValue` are of equal size and the struct has no padding, you can convert the underlying array of `KeyValue` elements to an array of `uint32`.

```
takeKeyValues((*[1 << 30]uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(&s[0]))[:len(s)*2])
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Jjkv9pdFITu

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to JimB's answer, you can also use the `reflect` (reflect.SliceHeader) and `unsafe` (unsafe.Pointer) packages to achieve this.

https://play.golang.org/p/RLrMgoWgI7t

```
s := []KeyValue{{0, 100}, {1, 101}, {2, 102}, {3, 103}}
var data []uint32
sh := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&data))
sh.Data = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&s[0]))
sh.Len = len(s) * 2
sh.Cap = sh.Len
fmt.Println(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I a bit puzzled by what you want. If the slice is dynamic, you have to *grow it dynamically* as you add elements to it (at the call site).

Go does not have `alloca(3)`, but I may propose another approach:

1. Come up with an upper limit of the elements you'd need.
2. Declare variable of the array type of that size (not a slice).
3. "Patch" as many elements you want (starting at index 0) in that array.
4. "Slice" the array and pass the slice to the callee.

Slicing an array does not copy memory — it just takes the address of the array's first element.

Something like this:

```golang
func caller(actualSize int) {
  const MaxLen = 42

  if actualSize > MaxLen {
    panic("actualSize > MaxLen")
  }

  var kv [MaxLen]KeyValue

  for i := 0; i < actualSize; i++ {
    kv[i].Key, kv[i].Value = 100, 200
  }

  callee(kv[:actualSize])
}

func callee(kv []KeyValue) {
  // ...
}
```

But note that when the Go compiler sees `var kv [MaxLen]KeyValue`, it does not *have to* allocate it on the stack. Basically, I beleive the language spec does not tell anything about the stack vs heap.